# Workaround using Waterline ORM with postGIS data types

Tags: sails.js, postgis, waterline

I'm using postGIS which has native datatypes for geometry objects. I'm using sailsjs as my middleware framework, which uses Waterline ORM. Obviously Waterline does not support postGIS geometry types; is there any workaround?

This question is the same as [Sailsjs Geospatial Solution with Waterline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005125/sailsjs-geospatial-solution-with-waterline) but there was no relevant answer.

Comment: Hey. What about https://github.com/waterlinejs/postgresql-adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no workaround -- instead, keep your geometry data types in separate 1:1 tables and keep track of them separately.